# How to find a string inside a code construct (foreach loop) in a code file?

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, code-analysis

I searched around for a similar question but could not find one.

Inside Visual Studio in my code files, I want to find all the foreach loops that contain a particular string of code?  I can easily do a find all foreach but that turns up hundreds and it would be too hard to double click each on to do a manual inspection?

eg.

```
foreach(var foo in foos)
{
Console.WriteLine("I need search for the string 'Console' inside the foreach.");
}
```

I thought of regular expressions but I have no idea how to write that.  Not sure if there is another way.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I guess a regex would be a good way to go. I am not a visual studio user but here's a regex you could use:

```
foreach\([^\)]+\)[^}]+(YOUR SEARCH STRING HERE)[^}]+}
```

Comment: I tried it but Visual Studio gave me back the following error:  Empty character set [] or [^] was specified.  I am not good at regex so not sure what it means.

Comment: maybe this will work, I don't know if } is a special character... foreach\([^\)]+\)[^\}]+(YOUR SEARCH STRING HERE)[^\}]+}

Comment: Thank you for your help but I it still not working.  VS is telling me there is a Syntax error in pattern now.  Not very helpful is it.